I have peer dependency issue about ts-api-utils with typescript version
First Error
I'm trying to using Yarn Berry v4.3.1 with Nest.JS
But there's a peer dependency issue about ts-api-utils.
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-node-externals": "^3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },

I tried set typescript version >=4.2.0, but there's same warning shows again.
Try to fix it
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-node-externals": "^3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.2.0"
  },

I expected no peer dependency warning and no issues.

Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of error messages, copy and paste or type the actual message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Oops Sorry….. I have to read rules….
